# creating the same jtable in 2 different JtabbedPanes

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtabbedpane, defaulttablemodel

I want to create 2 JTabbedPanes that will have the same JTable but different values in one of the columns. Right now for some reason only one of the tabs is showing up and I am not sure why. Also am I doing this the best way by creating 2 different `DefaultTableModel`'s?

```
public static void tableMaker(DefaultTableModel m, DefaultTableModel m1, final Map<String, NumberHolder> uaCount)
{
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Strings");     
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
            JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

    m.addColumn("String");
    m.addColumn("Occurrences");
            m1.addColumn("String");
    m1.addColumn("Occurrences");
    JTable table = new JTable(m);
            JTable table = new JTable(m1);
    table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
    JScrollPane scrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(table1);
            JScrollPane scrollPane2 = new JScrollPane(table2);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());                                                       
    panel1.add(scrollPane1);
            panel2.add(scrollPane2);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.getContentPane().add(panel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);        
    frame.add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    tabbedPane.setTabLayoutPolicy(JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT);
    tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 1", null, panel1,
                "String length 2");
    tabbedPane.addTab("Tab 1", null, panel2,
                "String length 2");
```

Comment: May I ask what is the purpose of having two tabs with the same information?

Comment: They `String` columns are going to have different information

Comment: But then it means that it cannot be the same table. You could maybe have some kind of combined table model where common information could be centralized and reused, but it will never be the same JTable.

Comment: @user2007843 You can also refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313240/java-same-arraylist-for-multiple-table-model/15314122#15314122) for the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want to create 2 JTabbedPanes that will have the same JTable but
>   different values in one of the columns. Right now for some reason only
>   one of the tabs is showing up and I am not sure why. Also am I doing
>   this the best way by creating 2 different DefaultTableModel's?

- create only one DefaultTableModel,
- then all changes are synchonized,
- each of JTables can have different ColumnModel, Renderers, etc

[simplest (SSCCE) code as is possible](http://sscce.org/)

[image][image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class MyTabbedPane {

    private JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    private JFrame f = new JFrame();
    private String[] columnNames = {"First Name", "Last Name", "Sport",
        "# of Years", "Vegetarian"};
    private Object[][] data = {
        {"Kathy", "Smith", "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), (false)},
        {"John", "Doe", "Rowing", new Integer(3), (true)},
        {"Sue", "Black", "Knitting", new Integer(2), (false)},
        {"Jane", "White", "Speed reading", new Integer(20), (true)},
        {"Joe", "Brown", "Pool", new Integer(10), (false)}
    };
    private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
            return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
        }
    };

    public MyTabbedPane() {
        tabbedPane.addTab("Tab1", new JScrollPane(new JTable(model)));
        tabbedPane.addTab("Tab2", new JScrollPane(new JTable(model)));
        tabbedPane.addTab("Tab3", new JScrollPane(new JTable(model)));
        tabbedPane.addTab("Tab4", new JScrollPane(new JTable(model)));
        tabbedPane.setTabPlacement(JTabbedPane.TOP);
        tabbedPane.setTabLayoutPolicy(JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MyTabbedPane frame = new MyTabbedPane();    
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: okay so I should use different JTables for the different tabs? Also why is only 1 tab showing up in the tabbedPane?

Comment: yes and to change default FlowLayout for JPanel to BorderLayout

Comment: +1. Small thing, you should rather use `Integer.valueOf` over `new Integer`.

Comment: @Guillaume Polet hmmm please is there significant difference???, another as good practicies how to decreasing (allocated) JVM memory

Comment: @mKorbel Of course not ;-) It's just good practice. Anyway, since Java 5, this is all unneeded since auto-boxing will do it for you.

Comment: @mKorbel: +1 for one model, many views. As an aside, `Integer.valueOf()` "is likely to yield significantly better space and time performance by caching frequently requested values."