# Creating a class that extends JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable in my panel and I would like to make a different class for it.

Here is my original code:

```
   Object[][] data = {
     // some data that the table will use    
    }

    JTable scoreTable = new JTable(data, columname);
    add(scoreTable);
```

I would like to wrap the data field in a class that extends JTable so I don't have to create them in my main class. I'm new to Java, how can I extend the JTable class so that when constructing the object the data is already set?

***LATER EDIT***: This was a really bad ideea from the time I had no clue how to make two classes and use them together. To keep the table creation, customization  and some properties related to it separated from Main class you should use [composition](http://www.journaldev.com/1325/what-is-composition-in-java-java-composition-example) rather than inheritance

Comment: Is there any question here ?

Comment: I want to answer your question. (This is an answer for your post).

Comment: @user714965  +1 to that.

Comment: @Alexandru Severin my [(maybe not important) question is please why whatever extend something](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-11-1998/jw-11-techniques.html)

Comment: Don't use `setBounds`, use an appropriate LayoutManager. ALWAYS!

Comment: Check out [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to extend `JTable`, you will still need to set the properties from outside of the class. I'm pretty sure you would be better of using a `Populator` or anything similar. This would be a class between your original class and the `JTable` that generates the `JTable` for you (and if desirable, returns it to the first class).

**Example**

```
class MyMain {
    void someMethod() {
        JTable table = (new Populator()).createJTable();
        add(table);
    }
}

class Populator {
    Object[][] data = {
        {" A", ""},
        {" B", ""},
        {" C", ""},
        {" D", ""},
        {" E", ""},
        {" F", ""},
        {" G", ""},
        {" H", ""},
        {" bonus", ""},
        {" Total", ""}
    };

    String[] columname = {"", ""};

    JTable createJTable() {
        JTable tabelscor = new JTable(data, columname);
        //tabelscor.setBounds(500, 120, 160, 250);
        tabelscor.setEnabled(false);

        return tabelscor;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 but [all those data could be local variables](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16222306/714968), against complicating simple things

Comment: @mrKorbel You're right. That would be an even better implementation since it's a `Populator`. Will edit, thanks for feedback!

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin You're welcome. Since you're new: in case you feel like my answer solves your question, consider accepting it :)